# Exclude 2 months (date)

Tags: php

I added a condition to my function. I would like if the new date ($dateSelect) falls between the 01 of July and the 30 of August that it shifts for the month of September and I would also exclude Sundays, if it falls on a Sunday it shifts to Saturday. That's what I already did:

```
function calcDate($date)
{
    $dateSelect = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($date)));
}
```

Do you have any idea how I can do that?

Thank you.

Comment: your question is not clear but you can also use `echo  $dateSelect = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+2 Months', strtotime($date)))`

Comment: I would like to check the variable $dateSelect and if it falls between July and August this date will be moved to September.

Comment: What day of september?

Comment: Still Unclear. :-(

Comment: For example, if the variable equals 2018-07-28, the new date must be 2018-09-28

Comment: No date possible in July and August to make it simple :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `date("m")` to find out what month it is in the new calculated date.
If it is within the period move it to september.

```
function calcDate($date)
{
    $m = date('m', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($date)));
    if($m >= 7 && $m< 9){
        $dateSelect = date('Y-09-d', strtotime($date));   
    }else{
        $dateSelect = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('+30 days', strtotime($date)));
    }
    $N =  date("N", strtotime($dateSelect));

    if($N >6) $dateSelect = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($dateSelect . " previous Saturday"));  

    return $dateSelect;
}

echo calcDate("2018-07-30"); // should return 30, but thats's a sunday. So 2018-09-29
```

https://3v4l.org/QSCvL

Comment: No problem! Feel free to upvote and/or accept if it's a good answer

Comment: If I do not want to count Sundays it's possible?

Comment: You mean if the date selected is a sunday make it the following monday?

Comment: Not Monday but the day before

Comment: You should edit your question and include all this too. If anyone else finds this question later they will read the question and my answer does not match the question. Include all your requirements in the question

Comment: It's true sorry, I add it.

Comment: added the request.